# How can a cloud-config script copy a file to a server?

Tags: cloud-init, cloud-config

How can a [cloud-config](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) script copy a file to a server?  `write_files` requires the file content in the script.  How can I specify an external file that contains the content?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You haven't given enough context to know for sure, but for the purposes of this answer I'll assume you're running in Amazon Web Services.

---

As per the cloud-init documentation [here](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/examples.html#writing-out-arbitrary-files), the only way to create a file directly via cloud-init is to include the file content in the script, either raw, base64-encoded, gzipped or base-64+gzipped.

Apart from doing that, the most straightforward way to do this would be to download the file - either via HTTP or an API call (for example, to S3).

Another way of getting the file onto the server would be to create a custom OS image (AMI) containing the file, by using something like [Packer](https://www.packer.io/).

Comment: I'm using CoreOS, but my question refers to the `cloud-config` (or `cloud-init`) specification, not any particular implementation.  I was wondering if there was some command that I had overlooked.  It seems that `cloud-config` scripts are designed to pull, not push files to the target server.

Comment: It also strikes me that cloud-config scripts are meant only to bootstrap a server, not fully provision it. A provisioning tool like Ansible seems more appropriate for more sophisticated configuration.

Comment: At that point why not use Ansible for everything. This absence of a decent way to get configuration files into instances its just bs.

Answer (score 0):

`scp` in the runcmd section can retrieve files, albeit in the final stage of cloud-init.